# possible to get default browser history in my application in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have created my own browser, but I want to get default browser history.

Comment: You have already asked this before. Asking again will not exactly help you. Try to formulate better your question.

Comment: what language are you using, environment etc

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722594/possible-to-get-default-browser-history-in-my-application-in-blackberry

Answer (score 3):

The title says default browser: No, there is no way to programmatically access the default browser history.

The content says "my own browser": with a BrowserField you can use the eventOccurred method to get the destination URL and build your own history.